# Swift: define a variable then conditionally set it?

Tags: swift

This is probably a very simple question...

Here I have some Swift code:

```
var url: NSURL
if (someValue > 1) {
    var fullUrl = self.baseUrl + "?id=" + (someValue as! String);
    var url = NSURL(string: fullUrl);
}
else {
    var url = NSURL(string: self.baseUrl);
}
let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
webView.loadRequest(req);
```

As you can see, I need to conditionally initialize the `url` variable. However, the method I've used in just about every other strong-type language - initialize the variable then assign to it in the if statement - doesn't seem to be the Swiftly way of doing it.

The above code will refuse to compile with the error "variable 'url' used for being initialized" error. (Of course, from this program flow, you can see that `url` would always be initialized, but Swift apparently takes nothing for granted.)

Not defining the variable outside the `if` block results in an unknown identifier error - it seems variables defined inside an `if` block are scoped only within that block.

Short of just defining an empty NSURL object, is there a better way to do this?

Preferably I'd actually like to use `let` on this because the NSURL object will never change once it's been created - and Swift tends to recommend using `let` wherever possible. However, how would you use `let` in this scenario? (I tried it - the same types of errors occur. Swift is unhappy that I don't actually declare the object itself on the same line as the `let` statement, but using `let` inside  the `if` block results in a scope issue.)

Comment: Removing `var` in front of the `url = NSURL(string: fullUrl);` should do the trick, no? Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring your property each time you try to set it. Try:

`url = /*stuff here*/;`

inside your if statements instead of:

`var url = /*stuff here*/;`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you're redefining `url` as `var url = NSURL(string: self.baseUrl);` within the context of the `if-else` so the `url` outside is never actually set.

This will fix the error and allow you to use `let` for `url`.

```
let url: NSURL
if (someValue > 1) {
    var fullUrl = self.baseUrl + "?id=" + (someValue as! String);
    url = NSURL(string: fullUrl);
} else {
    url = NSURL(string: self.baseUrl);
}
let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
webView.loadRequest(req);
```

Comment: Yes, the `var` turns it into a new declaration instead of an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define outside of the {}, that sets it's scope. In your code you're redefining url in the if and the else, you need to remove the re-declaration of "var" so that you can assign your url to the url out of the scope of the if / else statement.

You can use another if statement to check for nil and unwrap it if it's not nil, like

```
if url != nil {

    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You variable url need to be conditional do something like this.

```
var url: NSURL?
if (someValue > 1) {
   var fullUrl = self.baseUrl + "?id=" + (someValue as! String);
   url = NSURL(string: fullUrl);
}
else {
   url = NSURL(string: self.baseUrl);
}
let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
webView.loadRequest(req);
```